# Namespace of expression

Tags: php

```
namespace X {

    class X {
        public function __construct() {

        }

}

namespace Y {

    new X\X();

}
```

How to check in constructor of X what is the namespace of expression new X()? Only debug_backtrace and parsing file?

Comment: That's really none of X's constructor's business. The fact that you think you need this information indicates a flaw in your design. There's is no good reason for a constructor to need to examine its parent scope; anything it needs to know should be passed into it.

Comment: Suppose X wants to be a private class only for namespace X

Comment: That's not how "private" works, either the keyword or the concept of encapsulation. Trying to shoehorn in a solution that uses reflection is extremely backwards. If you don't want X's instantiated outside of namespace `X`, just *don't do it*.

Comment: You're absolutely right.